# Elasticsearch cluster health: yellow (131 of 262) unassigned shards

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I'm very new to Elasticsearch and try to use it for analyze of data from Suricata IPS. Head plugin shows me this: `yellow (131 of 262) unassigned shards`
also getting this:

```
$ curl -XGET http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch_brew",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 131,
  "active_shards" : 131,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 131,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0
}
```

How to get rid of those unassigned shards? And also Kibana says me this from time to time:

```
Error: Bad Gateway
    at respond (https://www.server.kibana/index.js?_b=:85279:15)
    at checkRespForFailure (https://www.server.kibana/index.js?_b=:85247:7)
    at https://www.server.kibana/index.js?_b=:83885:7
    at wrappedErrback (https://www.server.kibana/index.js?_b=:20902:78)
    at wrappedErrback (https://www.server.kibana/index.js?_b=:20902:78)
    at wrappedErrback (https://www.server.kibana/index.js?_b=:20902:78)
    at https://www.server.kibana/index.js?_b=:21035:76
    at Scope.$eval (https://www.server.kibana/index.js?_b=:22022:28)
    at Scope.$digest (https://www.server.kibana/index.js?_b=:21834:31)
    at Scope.$apply (https://www.server.kibana/index.js?_b=:22126:24)
```

I don't know if these problems connected to each other... Could please anyone help me to get it work. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A cluster with only one node and indices that have one replica will **always** be `yellow`.

`yellow` is not a bad thing, the cluster works perfectly fine. The downside is it doesn't have the copies of the shards active.

You can have a `green` cluster if youbset the number of replicas to 0 or you add a second node to the cluster.

But, as I said, there is no problem if you have a `yellow` cluster.

Setting number of replicas to 0, cluster wide (all indices):

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/_settings" -d'
{
  "number_of_replicas" : 0
}'
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. How can I let's say set number of replicas to 0?

Comment: I think my problem is actually deeper. There is something wrong with my cluster... Here is the link to my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31213429/kibana-4-with-apache-reverse-proxy-error-bad-gateway  Please help if you can. thank you!

Comment: there you go - now cluster is red(((

Comment: and then becomes yellow again((( Seems like after I restart elasticsearch daemon it works for a few minutes and stops for some reason((( I've actually found how to set number of replicas, it changed my cluster health to green but it still doesn't work properly((((